# Index signature in React props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm looking for a correct way to describe React props type in TS.

My component props is something like:

```js
interface Props {
  prop1: number,
  prop2: string,
}
```

But my components also accepts classNames as a prop (e.g. `_myClassName` well be converted to class `my-class-name`).

With props type above TS prints error `_myClassName doesn't exist on type Props`.
I've tried to change Props to:

```js
interface Props{
  prop1: number,
  prop2: string,
  [className: string]: any,
}
```

But in that case TS doesn't check type of prop1 and prop2. The following code will not produce error:

```js
<MyComponent prop1="some-string" /> // prop1 must be a number
```

So, is there a correct way to handle such cases?

Comment: You have two `prop1`, is that a typo?

Comment: No, this is not possible. This has been asked over and over but [adding an index signature breaks all other type safeties](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript). As to why this is not implemented, I don't know. You might want to ask this question at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. For everyone who will face the same issue:

```
interface Props {
  prop1: number,
  prop2: string,
}

export const MyComponent = <P extends Props>(props: P): React.ReactElement | null => {
  // code here
};
```

As the result we're get:

```
<MyComponent prop1="some-string" /> // error, prop1 must be a number

<MyComponent prop1={0} prop2="some-string" _myClassName /> // no error on additional prop, other props type checks
```